# SQL Columns Subquery with different criteria

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Lets say a have two tables, [Products] and [Quantiy].

I need to select a join in both in order to built a table with total Quantity per product.
I know who to do this in a vanilla join. My problem is that i need 3 columns one [PreviewTotal] where I should have this total quantity since ever till yesterday no matter sign of quantity other [TodaytotalPos] with quantity for today and positive and other [TodaytotalNeg] only today and negative.

result like:

```
[Products] [PreviewTotal]  [TodaytotalPos] [TodaytotalNeg]

AAPL           20,000         500             -700

MCD           15,000           NULL            -300

BAC           -30,000          2,000           NULL
```

Sample of structure:
Producst:

```
[id]  [name]
1     AAPL
2     MCD
3     BAC
```

Quantity:

```
[date]   [Id_Product]   [Quantity]
12/16         1            500
12/16         2            -300
12/17         1            1,000
12/18         3            5,500
12/18         1            -2,000
```

Comment: Could you provide table structure for Products and Quantity?

Comment: provide some sample data with desired output from that ...

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Express

Comment: Your desired results don't match the data going in, based on the rules that you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the rules you specify, I think you are just looking for conditional aggregation.  Your query would look something like this:

```
select p.name,
       sum(case when [date] < cast(getdate() as date) then quantity end) as PreviewTotal,
       sum(case when [date] = cast(getdate() as date) and quantity > 0
                then quantity end) as TodayTotalPos,
       sum(case when [date] = cast(getdate() as date) and
                quantity < 0 then quantity end) as TodayTotNeg
from products p join
     quantity q
     on q.id_product = p.id
group by p.name
order by p.name;
```

However, your desired results don't match the input data, based on these rules.

Comment: working perfect,thanks. Just one more thing, this select is part of a join. and end of all I want dont show a line if all this 3 calculated columns I have null.  Since Im using a SELECT/JOIN I think I must use HAVING , but it's not recognizing this 3 columns as argument.

Comment: ignore, just realized if all is NULL it dont include line by default.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use CASE to select a field value if a condition is true or false. I assume your [Products] table contains at least ProductId and ProductName, and your [Quantity] table contains at least ProductId, Qty, and SoldDate.

```
-- get the time of midnight, the start of today:
DECLARE Today datetime;
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101') INTO Today

-- get the totals
SELECT Products.ProductName, 
    SUM(
      CASE 
        WHEN Quantity.SoldDate >= Today THEN Quantity.Qty
        ELSE 0
      END) AS PreviewTotal,
    SUM(
      CASE 
        WHEN Quantity.Qty> 0 AND Quantity.SoldDate >= Today) THEN Quantity.Qty
        ELSE 0
      END) AS TodaytotalPos,
    SUM(
      CASE 
        WHEN Quantity.Qty< 0 AND Quantity.SoldDate >= Today THEN Quantity.Qty
        ELSE 0
      END) AS TodaytotalNeg
FROM Products JOIN Quantity on Products.ProductId = Quantity.ProductId
GROUP BY ProductName
```